# NeedIndexError on a single property (Google AppEngine + Firestore)

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Python (Standard Environment) application that I have uploaded to Google AppEngine, that uses Firestore for storage.

Here is a simplified version of my model class:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class User(ndb.Model):
    displayName = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def query_users(cls):
        query = cls.query().order(cls.displayName)
        db_objects = query.fetch()
        # do something with db_objects
```

This works as I would expect in a local development server (dev_appserver.py).

When I don't use a .order(cls.displayName) call, I don't get errors, but obviously the results are not sorted.

When I do use the .order(cls.displayName) call, I get the following error:

```
NeedIndexError: no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
- kind: User
  properties:
  - name: displayName
```

All of the (10-15 test) User documents have a displayName property in the Firestore instance being queried.  I thought Firestore generated an index for each single property?

I found a slightly similar [question regarding composite indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482669/firebase-datastore-need-index), but my issue is more about an index on a single property.

Also, the [indexes](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/indexes) page in the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) console for this project doesn't show any indexes and instead has this text:

```
To use Firestore during Beta, open the Firebase console.
```

The Firebase console indexes page ( https://console.firebase.google.com/project/$PROJECT_ID/database/firestore/indexes ) has no indexes listed, composite or otherwise.

I have an autogenerated index.yaml file with complex indexes (and no simple indexes).

I also have a firestore.indexes.json file with nothing specified at the moment :

```
{
  "indexes": []
}
```

(I created some database rules in a firestore.rules file and created this file at the same time.)

From reading the Firestore documentation on indexes, the firestore.indexes.json file is supposed to be for complex (multi-property) indexes, not for single-property indexes.

So, does Google AppEngine (GAE) / Google Cloud Platform (GCP, Python Standard Environment) play nice with Firestore indexes?

More importantly, does anyone have any ideas for how to solve this issue with single property indexes?

For a follow-on issue, is the index.yaml file ignored when Firestore is used for the data store?  Should I re-create the indexes in my index.yaml file in the firestore.indexes.json file and deploy that instead?

Comment: FYI, I cross-posted this to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/5427

Comment: Although I don't know the exact mechanism differences between Firebase Firestore and Cloud Datastore, it sounds to me like automatic key indexing in Datastore would be better suited for you even for simple entities.

Is there any special reason why you are using Firestore instead of Datastore? Firebase seems to me better suited if you need mobile SDKs.

Comment: We do need mobile SDKs as well as Python (web) SDKs, and Firestore is supposed to be the new new thing.

Comment: As I mentioned on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/issues/292 this is no longer relevant to me, as I gave up on trying to use NDB for firestore from GCP / App Engine.  I'm using the firestore module from the Firebase admin SDK instead now: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/